# The Squiggly Sequence

Tags: code-golf, string

## *[All credits to Adnan for coming up with this challenge.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32016426#32016426)*

My last challenge, before [I go on break](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31944993#31944993).

## Task

Given positive integer `n`, if `n` is odd, repeat `/` that many times; if `n` is even, repeat `\` that many times.

(Seriously, the testcases would be much clearer than this description, so just look at the testcases.)

## Specs

- Any reasonable input/output format.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

## Testcases

```
n output
1 /
2 \\
3 ///
4 \\\\
5 /////
6 \\\\\\
```

Answer (score 19):

## Javascript, 22 bytes

```
n=>"\\/"[n%2].repeat(n)
```

Defines an anonymous function.

If only `*` repeated strings in Javascript. *sighs*

Comment: Finally you have found the right operator

Comment: @LeakyNun What are you talking about?

Comment: You were using the ternary operator to choose the character, no?

Comment: @LeakyNun Initially, yes, but if you look at chat, I also posted this about a minute later.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice; my fault.

Comment: Your slashes are switched around.

Comment: @Scepheo Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: sorry for the ignorance (new here, and reading up a lot of code-golf questions).. How would one test this snippet?

Comment: @Jordumus You could either assign the function to a variable: `f=n=>...`, you could directly call it: `(n=>...)(5)`. (Or if you are using the Node.js REPL, then you could use `this._`, which stands for the last thing entered)

Answer (score 17):

### Python, 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\/'[n%2]*n
```

Comment: Great, simple and elegant ^_^

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)/[2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), <s>15</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
DÈ„/\sè×
```

*-2 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun*

*-1 byte thanks to Emigna*

[Try it online! in 05AB1E](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMOI4oCeL1xzw6jDlw&input=NA)
[or in 2sable](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=RMOI4oCeL1xzw6jDlw&input=NA)

Comment: [ftfy](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5DDiCIvXCJzw6jDlw&input=NA)

Comment: It says `sè×` 

Comment: `"/\"` can be „/\

Comment: You can remove the leading `D` for -1 byte in both languages, since input is implicit. You can also save an additional byte in _05AB1E (legacy)_ by changing ``È„/\`` to `„\/`, since indexing is modular. (PS: in the new version of 05AB1E it's even 1 byte less by removing the `s`, but [there is already an answer for that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215329/52210).)

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, 20 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with input on STDIN:

```
squigly.pl <<< 6
```

`squigly.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=$_%2x$_;y;01;\\/
```

Comment: It might just be my version of Perl (I'm still on 5.10) but this throws an error unless I add an extra ; to the end. I think it's because it you're using the semi-colon as a separator for y and you need one more to finish the statement (and would need two if you had more lines of code after this)

Comment: @theLambGoat Are you sure you are using the `-p` option ? I use `;` in the transliterate exactly because `-p` has an implicit `;` at the end of the code so I can save 1 more byte. This has worked since at least perl 5.6 (probably as long as the `-p` option existed in fact)

Comment: @theLambGoat Mm, I found an old redhat with perl 5.10 where indeed it does not work. Either this is a redhat patch or it indeed did not work for around 5.10 (I'm sure it worked in older perls and it also works in newer perls)

Comment: I'm running on SUSE Enterprise Server 11 so it's not just a redhat thing. But I think as long as it works in some versions, it should still be a valid answer. (I also just checked in 5.08, the only other version I have access to at the moment and it doesn't work there either)

Comment: Also 20 bytes: `$_=qw{\ /}[$_%2]x$_` but far less interesting than this one!

Comment: That trick with the `;` added by `-p` is quite awsome, well done.

Answer (score 8):

## J, 10 bytes

```
#'\/'{~2|]
```

This is a six-train verb, consisting of:

```
# ('\/' {~ 2 | ])
```

This is a hook between `#` and `('\/' {~ 2 | ])`; a hook `(f g) y` expands to `y f (g y)`, so this expands to `y # (... y)`, which, for single-characters, yields a list of `y` characters.

The second part is a 5-train, consisting of:

```
'\/' {~ 2 | ]
```

This evaluates to two forks:

```
'\/' {~ (2 | ])
```

The inner fork, `2 | ]`, is modulus two. The outer fork, therefore, is:

```
'\/' {~ mod2
```

Which takes (`{~`) the mod2 index (`mod2`) from the string `/`.

Then, using the hook from above:

```
y # (apt char)
```

This yields what we want, and we are done.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 21

```
.+
$*/
T`/`\\`^(..)+$
```

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouKwokKi8KVGAvYFxcYF4oLi4pKyQ&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjY) (First line added to allow multiple testcases to be run).

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 38 bytes

```
for(;$i++<$a=$argv[1];)echo'\/'[$a%2];
```

(variant 38 bytes)

```
while($i++<$a=$argv[1])echo'\/'[$a%2];
```

(variant 38 bytes)

```
<?=str_pad('',$a=$argv[1],'\/'[$a%2]);
```

(variant 40 bytes)

```
<?=str_repeat('\/'[($a=$argv[1])%2],$a);
```

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 42 bytes

```
string f(int n)=>new string("\\/"[n%2],n);
```

Selects the correct character, then creates a new string consisting of that character repeated `n` times.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 40 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=n;i--;)putchar(n%2?47:92);}
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/vf6w78)

Comment: `putchar(92-n%2*45)` is the same length.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ị⁾/\x
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4buL4oG-L1x4&input=&args=NA) or [Verify all testcases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4buL4oG-L1x4CjZSw4figqw&input=)

```
ị⁾/\x

ị⁾/\    modular-indexing into the string "/\"
    x   repeat
```

Comment: Although I suspect this challenge may have something to do with it existing, it's worth noting that `Ø^` is a byte shorter than `⁾/\ `.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 25 bytes

```haskell
f n=cycle"\\/"!!n<$[1..n]
```

-1 byte thanks to Damien with `cycle`.

Comment: `f n=cycle"\\/"!!n<$[1..n]`

Comment: @Damien Wow, how did I forget cycle.

Comment: I don't know. But I'm glad to have had the opportunity to "beat" you once :)

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
If[OddQ@#,"/","\\"]~Table~#&
```

Anonymous function. Takes an integer as input and returns a list of characters as output.

Comment: You can use `~Table~#`.

Comment: I think it was added in 10.2.

Comment: Also, I think you can ditch the `<>""` and return a list of characters.

Comment: @MartinEnder They must have also added `~Do~Infinity` and such in 10.2+ as well...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
"\\"["/"][[#~Mod~2]]~Table~#&
```

Cruelly exploits the fact that `[[1]]` returns the first argument of a function while `[[0]]` returns the function (head) itself, applied to the strangely valid function named `"\\"` which is being "evaluated" at `"/"`.

Comment: It's slightly less weird when you consider that something of the form `a[b]` is just a generic *expression* with head `a` (index `0`) and element `b` (index `1`), and functions are just special kinds of expression (actually, it would be more correct to say that functions aren't expressions at all, but are simply rules for transforming expressions which *usually* have form `f[x...]`). :)

Comment: I've seen many languages abused on this site, but I think this is the first abuse of Mathematica that I've seen. Good job!

Answer (score 5):

## Powershell, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

Update:

```
param($n)('\','/')[$n%2]*$n
```

Switching to `param`, thanks to [timmyd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/timmyd).

---

```
"$("\/"[$args[0]%2])"*$args[0]
```

or slightly more readable

```
("\","/")[$args[0]%2]*$args[0]
```

Test:

```
> 1..10 | % { ./run.ps1 $_ }
/
\\
///
\\\\
/////
\\\\\\
///////
\\\\\\\\
/////////
\\\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice to see another PowerShell user around here. You can shave a few bytes by taking input as `param($n)` instead of `$args`, like follows for 27 bytes -- `param($n)('\','/')[$n%2]*$n`

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 15 bytes

```
->n{'\/'[n%2]*n}
```

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/632030

Answer (score 4):

## Fourier, 27 bytes

```
92~SI~N%2{1}{47~S}N(Sai^~i)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=OTJ-U0l-TiUyezF9ezQ3flN9TihTYWlefmkp&input=Ng)

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems.

```apl
⊢⍴'\/'⊃⍨2|⊢
```

`⊢` the argument

`⍴` reshapes (repeats)

`'\/'⊃⍨` the string "/" selected by

`2|⊢` the division remainder when the argument is divided by two

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20f%u2190%u22A2%u2374%27%5C/%27%u2283%u23682%7C%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f%A81%202%203%204%205&run)

Comment: Cool! Very similar to J.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yes, the only difference is that 2-trains in J are hooks, while they are atops in Dyalog, so an explicit left tine is needed.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why the argument was there.

Comment: Finally an APL answer with all characters rendered correctly for me!

Comment: @Cyoce Yeah, I wish we could specify (and embed) fonts on SE.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
:2%:"\/"rm:?jbw
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjIlOiJcLyJybTo_amJ3&input=Ng)

#### Explanation

```
:2%                Input mod 2…
   :"\/"rm         …is the index of the element in string "\/",…
          :?j      …element that we juxtapose Input times to itself…
             bw    …and print to STDOUT after removing one slash/backslash
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 11, <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 29 bytes

```java
n->(n%2<1?"\\":"/").repeat(n)
```

-3 bytes saved thanks to *@user902383* and *@SeanBean*
-36 bytes switching from Java 7 to Java 11+

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoJADEX3fEUziclMCBjcyUO/QDYuxcUIgylCIcNAYgzfjsNj0Sbtve09lRylVxWfOa9l38NNIv0cACSjdClzBekyAtyNRnpDzq0CJCK7nBzbeiMN5pACQTKTd@F0OMXBlWUZC9mRCV@rTknDSczR4u@GV239@9nYYgGNzeTb/8dTii2vbPUahUkQYZycI3TdXbIw396oxm8H43f2zNTE0WUhMJd8SyhWvAVwqWn@Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                     // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  (n%2<1?               //  If `n` is even:
         "\\"           //   Use String "\"
        :               //  Else (`n` is odd):
         "/")           //   Use String "/" instead
             .repeat(n) //  Repeat it `n` amount of times
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. Why not a Lambda Expression?

Comment: @Vale Hi Vale. Because I'm an old-fashion Java 7 programmer. :) If you have a Java 8 or 9 answer that is slightly different than my answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: @Vale (he's odd like that :P)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I must admit I'm slowly switching too, so I'll post it as soon as I make it work! It doesn't help that the projects I'm following right now are all in Java 7 as well. I can't wait to transition completely. If anybody would like to intervene for the both of us, please do.

Comment: i think if you change `x=-1;++x<i` to `x=0;x++<i` you can reduce by one byte

Comment: Also you can replace `"\\"  : "/"` with `92:'/'` ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 9 bytes

```
ri_"\/"=*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmlfIlwvIj0q&input=NQ)

#### Explanation

```
ri     e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_      e# Duplicate N.
"\/"=  e# Use N as cyclic index into "\/", giving '\ for even and '/ for odd inputs.
*      e# Repeat N times.
```

Answer (score 4):

## ><> (Fish), 30 Bytes

```
:2%?'/'o1-:?!;30.
30.  >'\'50p
```

First time using this language, but I think I at least saved a little room by conditionally using the / as either part of the output or a mirror to redirect flow. Probably still horribly inefficient though, I feel like it could probably be cut down a little more at the very least.

Input is the initial stack, output is `stdout`

[Try it online!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/iR7o6DFo3MvNG5dWJ)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! I appreciate the welcome.

Answer (score 3):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
"\/"@aXa
```

Straightforward. Uses modular indexing to select the character and string repetition to multiply it. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=IlwvIkBhWGE&input=&args=NQ)

---

This question presents an interesting comparison between Pip, [Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91732/16766), and [Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91733/16766), the latter two each having scored 5 bytes. All three languages have implicit output, with single-char operators for modular indexing and string repetition, and no requirement to escape backslashes in strings. There are two key differences, though:

1. Under certain circumstances, Pyth and Jelly need only one delimiter to define a string;
2. Pyth and Jelly have syntax such that the input doesn't need to be explicitly represented in the code (though for very different reasons, as [Maltysen explained to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32067110#32067110)).

Neither one of these features is likely to show up in Pip<sup>1</sup> (I don't like the aesthetics of unbalanced delimiters, and point-free syntax or implicit operands seem like they would be too alien to my infix expression parser), but I'm okay with playing third fiddle. Even though "readability" is extremely relative when golfing, I'd argue that those three extra bytes make the Pip program a lot easier to understand at a glance--and in my book, that's a worthwhile tradeoff.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Although, single-character strings in Pip use a single `'` delimiter, inspired by CJam and by quoting in Lisp.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure that readability is a plus, in code golf?   Not at the cost of *bytes* !

Comment: @GreenAsJade I expect a lot of people feel the same. I would just make one distinction: `code golf` != `golflang design`. Now you may well argue that the same principle (shorter is always better) applies to language design too. I'm just saying that for me, usability and even aesthetics *are* considerations.

Comment: Pro tip for making a golfing language: don't use infix

Comment: @Cyoce http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31933195

Comment: pyth doesn't have implicit point free syntax. it works pretty much the same way it does in python, making it readable yet short. your comment about the unbalanced delimiters on the other hand is pretty true

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 20 bytes

```
!x="$("/\\"[x%2])"^x
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
n=scan();cat(rep(c("\\","/")[n%%2+1],n),sep="")
```

In R, you have to escape backslashes. the argument `sep` also has to be fully specified since it comes after `...`. Thus annoyingly few opportunities to save chars :(

Thanks to bouncyball for golfing away a byte.

Comment: Save one byte by using indexing: `n=scan();cat(rep(c('\\','/')[n%%2+1],n),sep='')`

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL 50 bytes

Of course no `STDIN` here, so let's assume a hardcoded `INT` variable like this: `DECLARE @ INT` then the solution is:

```
PRINT IIF(@%2=0,REPLICATE('\',@),REPLICATE('/',@))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Psithurism, 11 bytes

```
*(%2?"/:"\)
```

This is a language I'm still developing, but I'm going to start posting answers here to get a feeling of what kind of built-in functions might be useful to have. (This one has taught me I really need some way to index into arrays/strings lol.)

explained:

```
*(        # implicitly multiply the input by
  %2      # implicitly take input mod 2
    ? "/  # / if truthy (1)
    : "\  # \ if falsy (0)
)
```

Curious about Psithurism?
Github: https://github.com/AroLeaf/psithurism/
Docs (soon™): https://psithurism.leaf.moe/

Comment: I don't think it's non-competing since we dropped the rule that languages have to be older than the challenge.

Comment: @TheThonnu oh that's nice, thanks! I do assume that implementing a feature to improve your score is still non-competing?

Comment: If you make the feature *just* for that challenge, yeah it's non-competing, but if you make a feature which generally improves the language, and improves your score as a side effect, then that's fine.

Comment: @TheThonnu alright, thanks for clarifying

Comment: So for your example adding indexing would be fine in my opinion, because it's a useful feature for many challenges. [Related loophole on Meta if you want more info.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12714/114446)

Comment: Also, [related Meta post about answering in newer languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/114446).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
*@"\/
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a%40%22%5C%2F&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

Modular-indexing into the string `\/` and then repeat.

Comment: You're FGITW'ing your own challenge?

Comment: @xnor it isn't exactly my challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 16 bytes

```perl6
{<\ />[$_%2]x$_}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
for 1..6 {
  say $_, {<\ />[$_%2]x$_}( $_ )
}
```

```perl6
1/
2\\
3///
4\\\\
5/////
6\\\\\\
```

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - 28 bytes

```
1 INPUT n: ?"\/"(ODD(n)+1)*n
```

`ODD` returns 1 if number is odd, then uses that as an index to print the correct character n number of times. Have to add 1 as SpecBAS strings start at character 1.

Answer (score 2):

## **Python 3, 43 Bytes**

```
n=int(input())
a='\\'*n
if n%2:a='/'*n
print(a)
```

In python the `\` symbol is also used as an operator when inside a string (e.g: `\n` means newline) so `\\` has to be used to get the backslash symbol.

This code works by assuming the input (`n`) is odd, and then checks if it is even. If so, then it redefines the variable `a` (the output) before displaying it.

This is shorter than using an `if-else` statement by 5 bytes as it does the checking after defining the variable, meaning that the `else` command is not needed.

Comment: You could save bytes by changing to Python2, since `int(input())` could be changed to `input()` and `print` wouldn't need parentheses. Also, there's an unnecessary whitespace in `n%2: `.

Comment: Also, you may hook the character from a string (selecting n%2-th) character, but that would end up being the same answer as @xnor has. It's a nice trick for the future!

Comment: Indeed, `'\/'[n%2]*n` is pretty much as short as it can be.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll bear them in mind for next time

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 56 bytes

```
(i,j)->{for(j=i;j-->0;)System.out.print(i%2<1?92:'/');};
```

I'd like to thank @Kevin Cruijssen in advanced for golfing my answer further.

## Ungolfed Test Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer = (i, j) -> {
        for (j = i; j-- > 0;) {
            System.out.print(i % 2 < 1 ? 92 : '/');
        }
    };

    consumer.accept(5, 0);
    consumer.accept(1, 0);
    consumer.accept(8, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash + coreutils, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```sh
yes $1_45r2%*92+P|sed $1q|dc
```

Previous answer, easier to understand:

```sh
yes $[92-$1%2*45]P|sed $1q|dc
```

In the new script I just transferred the calculation of the ASCII code from bash to dc entirely.

Comment: @LeakyNun I was used with the Bash and pure Bash terms until I started here. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>63</s> 52 bytes

**Version 1** - 63 bytes

```
$i=$argv[1];$x=($i%2?"/":"\\");echo sprintf("%'".$x.$i."s",$x);
```

**Version 2** - 52 bytes

<sup>Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving 11 bytes</sup>

```
$i=$argv[1];$x=$i%2?"/":"\\";printf("%'$x{$i}s",$x);
```

Run with `php -f squiggle.php <number>`

https://repl.it/DFdi/2 (remember to [change the input on repl](https://i.gyazo.com/ee8c0d2cd0c10d57aaf7c99e8473ed7d.gif))

Comment: No need for parenthesis around the ternary expression. Why using `sprintf()` to return a value just to `echo` it and not directly `printf()` it? And is shorter to use variable expansion than concatenating the format string: `"%'$x{$i}s"`.

Comment: @manatwork thanks for the great tips! I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Actually, 10 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OydcJy8yKCVJKg&input=MTE)

```
;'\'/2(%I*
```

**How it works**

```
       Implicit input of n
;      Duplicate n
'\'/   The strings "/" and "\"
2(%    n mod 2
I      If n mod 2, then "/", else "\"
*      Multiply by n. Implicit print at the end.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 15 + 3 = 18 bytes

```
\/:l2-),:2%0go:
```

+3 bytes for the `-v` flag to initialise the stack with the input. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=XC86bDItKSw6MiUwZ286&input=&args=LXYgNA)

><> is a toroidal 2D language, so the following runs in a loop:

```
\/          Mirrors that reflect the instruction pointer. Since the code is
            one row high, the reflection wraps and the IP ends up moving in the
            same direction anyway, so these are no-ops.

:l2-)       Push (input > length of stack - 1) - note that the actual subtraction
            is by 2 to account for the fact that we duplicated an element with :

,           Divide the input by the above. If (input == length of stack - 1),
            then the program errors out due to division by 0. Otherwise, the
            input is unchanged.

:2%0g       Push the char at (input % 2, 0), which will be one of the two slashes
            at the beginning of the code

o           Output this char

:           Duplicate the input, increasing the length of the stack by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
R¹!"/¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@jQTkUl/UPL/v//bwQA)

-4 bytes from Zgarb.

`¦` is an alias for `\` in a string.

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
*⁰;!⁰"/\\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X@tR4wZrRSChpB8To/T//38zAA)

### Explanation

```
*⁰;!⁰"/\\"
   !⁰"/\\" get element at index n in string "/\" (wraps around)
  ;        create singleton list from it
*⁰         repeat list n times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
çUg"\\/
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=51VnIlxcLw&input=Ng)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 55 bytes

```forth
: b 1- dup for dup 2 mod if 92 else 47 then emit next ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCoAgEEbhfaf4L@BCC6K6TTmmkBo2QbefzFYfPHguF/Zqdx8iM1ZoBXufqKVpELNFcJgM6LgIwwj2lEAxMBI9jEV0/bbSmZ@@IS8)

called as `<number> b`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).*

```
„\/è×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8GP3DKw5P///fGAA)

```
     è   # 0-based index...
         # implicit input...
     è   # implicit mod 2 in...
 „\/     # "\/"
      ×  # repeat implicit input times
         # implicit output
```

Comment: `è` is a) modular, so you don't need `É`, and b) commutative, so you don't need `s`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 31 bits<sup>1</sup>, 3.875 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
‛\/iẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oCbXFwvaeG6iyIsIiIsIjIzIl0=)

```
'\/    # string literal "\\/"
   i   # modular index
    ẋ  # repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
?£₂k/i¥ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCI/wqPigoJrL2nCpeG6iyIsIiIsIjIzIl0=)

Comment: [5 bytes because of implicit input](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCLigoJrL2nhuosiLCIiLCIyMyJd) or [4.75 bytes in Vycoder](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oKCay9p4bqLIiwiIiwiMjMiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## TypeScript's Type System, No Ignore, <strike>541 311 155 148 140</strike> 118 bytes

*Based off of a previous [even/odd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/260630#260630) answer*

```
type E<N>=N extends`11${infer R}`?R extends""?"/":E<R>:"\\"
type X<A,B=A>=B extends`1${infer R}`?`${E<A>}${X<A,R>}`:""
```

X takes in a repeated 1 N times to represent the number N, for example `X<"11111">` represents 5 passed to the `X` function.

[TypeScript Playground && Tests](https://tsplay.dev/mqYG2m)

- Drastic improvements by [Jacob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/jacob) via even/odd, input simplification, and joining together types

Comment: 175 bytes https://tsplay.dev/WPgoKm

Comment: I do want to make sure I didn't mess it up - was that 175 bytes of improvement or 175 bytes total? (If it was total, it seems I couldn't do the minification right - I was only able to shave off 230 bytes by minifying your solution - the extra improvements came from dropping the unneeded conditional on `Join` and simplifying `infer _` to `any`)

Comment: 175 total - the part after the blank line is footer, which shouldn't be counted, unless you still want to take input in decimal. But then I'm sure there's a shorter way of converting decimal to unary, I didn't attempt to golf that section. Good idea with the `${any}` -- I didn't think of that.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks, I'll edit the solution with that input instead.

Comment: 148 bytes (I think you copy-pasted from the wrong link I posted earlier) https://tsplay.dev/Nll1XN

Comment: Even further, (didn't see this before) you can use `&string` instead of `N extends string` to coerce the type to be stringified: https://tsplay.dev/wR0o1m

Comment: (Golf stackexchange reccomended for us to [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145760/discussion-between-leodog896-and-jacob)).

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
▽∶?@/@\\◿2.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa94oi2P0AvQFxc4pe_Mi4KCiZwIGYgMgomcCBmIDMKJnAgZiA0)

```
▽∶?@/@\\◿2.
          .  # duplicate
        ◿2   # modulo two
  ?@/@\\     # choose slash depending on result
▽∶           # repeat it input times
```

Comment: Tried [all sorts of ideas](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa94oi2P0AvQFxc4pe_Mi4KZiDihpAgXOKKmTvih4zihq_ima3iiLYiL1xcIgpmIOKGkCDihq_iiLbiio_il78yLCJcXC8iCmYg4oaQIC3DlzQ14pe_MuKItuKGryxAXFwKZiDihpAg4oqP4oi2IlxcLyLil78y4oavLgpmIOKGkCArQFxcw5fCrzQ14pe_MuKGry4KZiDihpAg4oqP4oip4pa9Li7iiLYiXFwvIgoKJnAgZiAyCiZwIGYgMwomcCBmIDQ=) only to get a tie or 1 longer :/

Comment: @Bubbler Wow, that's a lot of ideas!

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 55 bytes

```
readIO
c=i
c%2
c*45
c-92
c|
lbla
printChar c
i-1
if i a
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cmVhZElPCmM9aQpjJTIKYyo0NQpjLTkyCmN8CmxibGEKcHJpbnRDaGFyIGMKaS0xCmlmIGkgYQ&input=&args=NQ)

Port of [this answer in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91728/48934).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
f n=replicate n$"\\/"!!(mod n 2)
```

Comment: `replicate n x` can be replaced by `[1..n]>>[x]` or `x<$[1..n]` (with GHC 7.10). You can find other haskell tricks here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell

Answer (score 1):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 21 bytes

```
[$2÷%'/'\2øø4ø2␂{␋},]
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
5[$2÷%'/'\2øø4ø2␂{␋},]!
```

## Explanation

```
[                    ]  [lambda]%
 $2÷%                   [copy input and mod 2]%
     '/'\2øø            [choose either / or \ depending on input mod 2]%
            4ø          [get input again]%
              2␂{      [copy the /\ char and the input into a new stack]%
                  ␋},   [repeat the stack by the input and output the stack]%
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 63 bytes

```
q(){ seq -s0 0 $1|cut -c-$1|tr 0-9 $(($1%2))|sed 'y/10/\/\\/';}
```

Comment: Weird. If you know the `tr` command, then why used `sed` for the 2nd transliteration?

Comment: Move your code outside of the function and drop the `q(){}` part. Also, you can drop both `tr` and `sed` conversions by doing something like this: `c=(\\ /);seq -s${c[$1%2]} 0 $1|tr -d [0-9]`. For an even shorter way see [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91725/the-squiggly-sequence/91826#91826)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, <s>210</s> 190 Bytes

```
fn main(){let x:usize=std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap().parse::<usize>().unwrap();let l:&str=match x%2{0=>"\\",1=>"/",_=>"",};println!("{}",std::iter::repeat(l).take(x).collect::<String>());}
```

Ungolfed:

```
fn main() {
    let x : usize = std::env::args().nth(1)
                                    .unwrap()
                                    .parse::<usize>()
                                    .unwrap();
    let l : &str = match x % 2 {
        0 => "\\",
        1 => "/",
        _ => "",
    };
    println!("{}", std::iter::repeat(l).take(x)
                                       .collect::<String>());
}
```

I don't usually golf (so I bet this isn't a great score, at least for Rust), but I figured this would be good Rust practice. This compiles into an executable run as `squiggly.exe x` where x is the number of times to repeat the character.

Comment: Cut off 20 bytes by realizing that direct referencing (`std::env::args()`, `std::iter::repeat(l)`) is more effective than use clauses

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 26 bytes

```
NF=$1,$1=OFS=$1%2?"/":"\\"
```

`$1` is the input and then part of the output

`NF` is the number of fields

`OFS` is the output field separator

It prints if the expression before the comma is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (<s>33</s> 44 Bytes)

Never tried golfing with Lua before.

Shortest program I could come up with:

`n=io.read()print(({'\\','/'})[n%2+1]:rep(n))`

Comment: Your code should handle either input or parameter.

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

Leaves `n%2` as junk on the stack. Output is sent to stdout. `47` is `/`, and `92` is `\`. Computes [`y=92-45*x`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line%20through%20(0,92),(1,47)), where `x` is `n%2` and emits (outputs) the character with that codepoint.

```forth
: f dup 2 mod swap 0 DO dup 92 swap 45 * - emit LOOP ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DKsE)

Answer (score 1):

## PL-SQL (Oracle), 530 characters

```sql
DECLARE
-- Enter your input here, here example is taken as 3 ---
  n number := 3 ;
  k varchar2(20);
BEGIN 
     -- Checking the input number for odd --
     if mod(n,2)=1 then      
     for j in 1..n loop 
      k := k||'/';           
      end loop; 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line (n||' '||k); 
     end if;

     -- Checking the input number for even --
         if mod(n,2)=0 then
         for j in 1..n loop
         k := k||'\';         
          end loop;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line (n||' '||k); 
         end if; 
END;
```

Comment: Language name?.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please put what language this is and the length in bytes at the top of your post. Also, remove as many extraneous characters as possible, including whitespace. Posters must make a serious effort to golf (shorten) their code for [code-golf] questions.

Answer (score 1):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 90 bytes

```
N
Count i while _%60-10 {
_*10+_%60*50-2880+N
}
_/60
Count j while _-j {
Write 92-_%2*45
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXtXMQNfQQKGaK17L0EAbxNUyNdA1srAw0PbjquWK1zczgGrJgmnRzQIqDy/KLElVsDTSjVc10jIx5ar9/9/QAAA)

#### With comments

```
# Read a line of stdin, convert it to a decimal number, and store it in the accumulator
N
Count i while _%60-10 {
    _*10+_%60*50-2880+N
}
_/60
# Loop that many times
Count j while _-j {
    # Output \ if accumulator mod 2 is 0, or / if it is 1
    Write 92-_%2*45
}
```

Comment: Acc!! is a really fun language!

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 38 bytes

```
%@!!2P2WA{~[67W5M;1A].}~[99W25W1MM;1A]
```

Made using Dion's modulus function from [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209401/80214)

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%2021.6px%3B%22%3E%25%40!!2P2WA%7B%7E%5B67W5M%3B1A%5D.%7D%7E%5B99W25W1MM%3B1A%5D%3C%2Fspan%3E&input=5)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, PC DOS, 18 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: a082 002c 30a8 0191 b85c 0a74 02b0 2fcd  ...,0....\.t../.
00000010: 10c3                                     ..
```

Listing:

```
A0 0082     MOV  AL, BYTE PTR[82H]  ; first char of command line into AL
2C 30       SUB  AL, '0'            ; ASCII convert input char
A8 01       TEST AL, 1              ; set ZF if even
91          XCHG AX, CX             ; CL = number of times to repeat
B8 0A5C     MOV  AX, 0A5CH          ; AL = '\', AH = 0AH (BIOS write char)
74 02       JZ   WRITE              ; if even, write with a '\'
B0 2F       MOV  AL, '/'            ; otherwise change to a '/'
        WRITE:
CD 10       INT  10H                ; write AL to console CX number of times
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

Standalone PC DOS executable (COM) program.  Input `n` on command line (note: this is limited to single digit values).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
*@"\/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8tBKUb//3@Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

```
*@"\/
@("\/", Q) * Q  // After implicit input is read and re-structured to appear more readable.
@("\/", Q)      // Get element at index Q(input)
@("\/", Q) * Q  // Repeat Q times.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```
$->n->repeat(0=n%2)?->{\}->"/"n
```

or

```
$->n[s:[{\}"/"]repeat s\[n%2]n]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?rMsgqH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 56 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU6xCsIwFNz7FUdAeBnE1rG0g6ODkzhZkVjT8iSmkj4HKf322GofHNxx3N3ra@NM7G4PWwsOGOLdNqiJ870XXTZdoGuxziAdWA@vwF6IG@LVtsi0qiplXW/VRukxAnP0adiTCW2fYxeC@ZyPMoXai85x8iwoMSSYbmoGMYo1Ury9sEOW6sXD/IBe6G/TefrrMZkxJvEL)

```scala
def c(i:Int)=for(_<-1 to i){print(if(i%2<1)"\\"else"/")}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BS8NAEIXv@RWPgLB7UBuPoRF68ODBk9VLW2TdbsrIZlJ2VrGU/va4G9IqHmYY3sy894k13gxD//7hbMQTjgVA3d6TpQjrjQgeOT58R8dCPYv6Mh5UZ1HDZXkrWPDhNcn5F9i6FpE6J6vlRrU1mnssdY0XTobNdAO0fYB6w/waFWIP0pdN2k3TqTj3XNnXqnN0A7oZU3DEPhBHRS0U4Qp3mKPSKNfrEs6LQ3lb6otDZ4iVCTupsQjBHFbPMX3vNv8JRz7KfDN8ciSPavbLmDj0NI7hnpX@A3sqhuEH)

```scala
object M {
  implicit class IntExtensions(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
    def times[T](f: => T): Unit = {
      for (_ <- 1 to i) {
        f
      }
    }
  }
  //def c(i:Int)=print(Iterator.fill(i)(if(i%2<1)"\\"else"/").mkString)
  //def c(i:Int)=Iterator.fill(i)(if(i%2<1)"\\"else"/").foreach(print)
  def c(i: Int) = i.times { print(if (i % 2 < 1) "\\" else "/") }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {
      c(i)
      println()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 28 bytes

```rust
|n|[r"\","/"][n%2].repeat(n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9NbsIwEEbXzikmlirZklNUaCtU1F6iyxChLGwUiQ7BHm8acpJusii34BjdcJtOMGHjn3nfjN78_PoYaLgoh_BVN6h0l4mdJXBv4FDF0HxbDcUHfJJvcAvvp0iuWJ6PeCy9XEsjZ7Iq8WFePXrb2poU6hS5_IlVJlruoh3mSqKBfaQ2ktRcd3sPiks1Bg0NQpkJoZ4M8DhtxvfcAM9f336Lkcwm9pzYnb4keuevE78lKt4pmbBHh_3VQNQhWE8be8iVY-vkspqSV2cDXc_HiEfSZ33abRjS_Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 32 bytes

```r
\(n)intToUtf8(rep(92-45*n%%2,n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3FWI08jQz80pC8kNL0iw0ilILNCyNdE1MtfJUVY108jQ1Ier2puUXaWQqZOYpGFoZGmgqJCeWaKRpZGrqKMXkKUHVLFgAoQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
`\/i×
```

##### Explanation

```python
`\/i×  # Implicit input
`\/    # Two character string "\\/"
   i   # Modularly index in
    ×  # Repeat input times
       # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 22 bytes

```
(/{1/($~1%2)}|\\){$~1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboW2zT0qw31NVTqDFWNNGtrYmI0q4HsWogkVM3iaJNYKBMA)

#### Explanation

```
(/{1/($~1%2)}|\\){$~1}
 /                      Match a forward slash
  {         }           repeated this many times:
   1/(     )             Invert:
      $~1                 Command-line argument
         %2               mod 2
                         (For odd arguments, this gives one forward slash; for even
                         arguments, it fails due to division by zero)
             |          If the previous alternative failed,
              \\        match a backslash instead
(               ){$~1}  Repeat the above (command-line argument) times
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 17 bytes

```
'\'/n:2%Isp[,lo];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/189Rl0/z8pI1bO4IFonJz/W@v9/YwA)

I tried a couple variations and this one was the shortest.  It's uses the eveness/oddness of the number to pick the character from a list on the stack, then stashes it away before looping "N" times and printing the saved character.  The stack ends up with junk on it so it explicitly exits to avoid printing it.  That proved shorter than cleaning the stack.

```
'\'/               - push "\/" onto the stack
    n:             - get number "N" from STDIN and duplicate
      2%           - get 0|1 depending on whether it's even or odd
        I          - copy top "\" or one-down "/" entry from stack
         sp        - stash the char and delete
           [,  ]   - loop "N" times
             lo    - load char to print, print it
                ;  - exit to avoid printing junk on the stack
```